# Swift background music delay

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, avaudioplayer

I'm trying to make background music loop seamlessly while having a part that doesn't loop, but there is a delay when switching the AVAudioPlayers. The delay happens when songA stops and songB starts. 
Here is the code.

```
lazy var songA: AVAudioPlayer? = {
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "A", withExtension: "wav") else {
        return nil
    }
    do {
        let player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        let x = player
        x.delegate=self
        player.numberOfLoops = 0
        player.prepareToPlay()
        return player
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}()
lazy var songB: AVAudioPlayer? = {
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "B", withExtension: "wav") else {
        return nil
    }
    do {
        let player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        player.numberOfLoops = -1
        player.prepareToPlay()
        return player
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}()
func multiTrack(songA: AVAudioPlayer, songB: AVAudioPlayer) {
    masterStop()
    songA.play()
    while songA.isPlaying==true {
        if songA.isPlaying==false{
            songB.play()
            songA.stop()
            songA.prepareToPlay()
        }
    }
    songB.play()
    songA.stop()
    songA.prepareToPlay()
    songA.currentTime=0
}
```

Comment: This topic has already been thoroughly discussed.  Initialize variables or use a singleton ahead of time.  I would vote to close this topic.

Comment: Where has it been discussed? I looked and couldn't find anything. Also, I thought I had initialized the variables.

Comment: If you initialize variables at the very time when you play back audio, that'll be too late.

Comment: I thought I was initializing them with lazy. Also there was one function I left out. masterStop looks like this and is before func multiTrack: `func masterStop(){
        songB?.stop()
        songB?.prepareToPlay()
        songB?.currentTime=0}`